# FileSystem not working in html code from seperate file

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to make a website that will play music notes from A-G at random and your goal is to guess them, I'm planning on storing the note mp3s in a separate folder, but at the moment I'm just trying to get it to take one song from the said folder, but it's not working, it can take mp3s from it if inputted manually, but not automatically.

Doesn't work:

```
const fs = require(`fs`);
let tones = fs.readdirSync(`./tones/`).filter((f) => { return f.endsWith(`.mp3`); });
let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * tones.length); //This is always equal to zero because tones only has one file 

function start() {
    let audio = new Audio(`./tones/${tones[i]}`);
    audio.play();
};
```

Does work:

```
const fs = require(`fs`);
let tones = fs.readdirSync(`./tones/`).filter((f) => { return f.endsWith(`.mp3`); });
let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * tones.length);

function start() {
    let audio = new Audio(`./tones/Sample.mp3`);
    audio.play();
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid `fs` is from node.js which runs on the server

Comment: And that means?

Comment: that means you can't use `fs` on html script

Comment: can you share your project folder structure?